# Does my ruby thread code will run in parallel automatically when use jRuby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

I have this code

```
require 'thread'
work_q = Queue.new
(0..50).to_a.each{|x| work_q.push x }
workers = (0...4).map do
  Thread.new do
    begin
      while x = work_q.pop(true)
        50.times{print [128000+x].pack "U*"}
      end
    rescue ThreadError
    end
  end
end
workers.map(&:join)
```

I know if I run using MRI, it's only run concurently.

But If I run it on jRuby will it run concurently and parallel, or just concurently

Is it mandatory to write thread code using java on jRuby to achieve the parallel process?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, it will be parallel. jruby ships with a custom thread library written in native java, so when you put `require 'thread'` at the top of your file, you're actually using a java library, not a ruby library.

As long as your java installation supports parallel threads (and most modern ones do), and as long as your operating system supports parallel threads (most mordern ones do), then your jruby code has the potential to run in parallel as well.

Comment: Ah nice. great to know that. one more question. how we proof that it's run in parallel.

Comment: @SunuPinasthikaFajar if you're on Windows, you can open Task Manager, go to the Performance tab, right click and select `Change Graph to > Logical processors`. This will allow you to monitor all of your processor cores to see if your code is running on all of them or one of them.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can use the `htop` command to see on which cores your process is running.

Comment: "Java threads are wrappers for native system threads, so they're parallel out of the box." – That is not true. 1) You are implying that native threads are automatically parallel and green threads aren't. That's wrong. E.g. YARV threads are *also* "wrappers for native system threads", and they are *not* parallel, whereas BEAM's threads are green threads, yet parallel. 2) There is no guarantee in the Java Language Specification that says anything about how threads are implemented, nor does it say anything about whether or not they are parallel. It is perfectly valid to implement Java with …

Comment: … non-parallel threads, and it is perfectly valid to implement Java with green threads, and there *are* green-threaded Java implementations, non-parallel threaded Java implementations, and both. In fact, Sun's implementation of Java used to be one of those. 3) even *if* Java threads are implemented as native system threads, it is perfectly possible for native system threads to *not* be parallel. There are plenty of operating systems on which threads are not parallel. 4) Even *if* your OS has parallel threads, they can still only execute in parallel if you have multiple CPUs. There are plenty …

Comment: … of machines that don't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks, i've updated my answer to be less misleading.